# How to remove the thick border produced when applying ADAPTIVETHRESH - Wellner's adaptive thresholding

Tags: matlab, image-processing

With reference to the mentioned links below:-

Image1: [image]

Image2: [image]

Image 2 is obtained after the application of `adapthisteq` followed by **Wellner's adapive threshold**

Can somebody help me in removing that thick border please, because when processing the image,  the coordinates for the image border is also being extracted. I have tried the `imclearborder` but those veins touching the border is also getting removed.

Also, I am having the impression that the vein patterns in image 2 has increased in size when compared to image 1.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images you provided aren't the same size. But the below code is the general idea:

Code:

```
hand = imread('hand.png'); % this the hand
hand = hand(1:235,1:309);
thresh = imread('thresh.png'); % this is the "veined" image with the large border
thresh = thresh(:,:,1);

thresh(hand < 100) = 256;

figure, imshow(thresh)
```

Output:

[image]

Basically, just do a simple threshold on the fist. Select these points through logical indexing. Then, set the value of these indices in the "veined" picture to the white value (either 1 or 256 depending if it's logical or not).

Also, the slight black bordered region to the right will go away if the images you provide are the same size and aligned. I'd also recommend using `imdilate` with `imerode` to get rid of the small bits.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jucestain. That works perfectly. To remove the noise (small bits) I have applied median and wiener filters and they got erased. Still, I will try what you recommended (imdilate and imerode). Yes, the uploaded images are not the same size because it is a printscreen. It is when I run them from my application that I have the impression they are of different size. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2265058 For a more robust solution you might also try using an edge detector and then `convhull` to get the boundary of the hand. This might be more robust if it's difficult to define a threshold for the hand.